# How to iterate over object item lists

Tags: python

I have the following class with a few items which are lists

```
class productConstructor:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.product_code = [1,2,3,4]
        self.quantity = [70,50,110,10]
        self.material = ['wood', 'metal', 'cork', 'cardboard']
```

What I need to do be able to do is loop over each item in the class and pick out the first item in the list so that if I do something like the following:

```
product = productConstructor('product')
```

I want to be able to for loop over 'product' and be able to access the nth index in the list of each item. This needs to be integrated with Flask for which the code looks like this:

```
{% for product in product%}
<div>
    <p>{{product.product_code}}</p>
    <p>{{product.quantity}}</p>
    <p>{{product.material}}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The Flask code should generate a div for each index in the list. For example I have 4 values in each object item list so what I'm expecting to happen is to have 4 divs that looks like this

div 1:
product_code = 1, quantity = 70, material = wood

div 2:
product_code = 2, quantity = 50, material = metal.

...and so on for div 3 and 4.

Can I achieve something like this with **iter** and **next** functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `__iter__` method to `productConstructor` that uses `zip` to pair the values and `yield`s an object with the desired attributes:

```
class Product:
   def __init__(self, _vals):
      self.__dict__ = dict(zip(['product_code', 'quantity', 'material'], _vals))

class productConstructor:
  def __init__(self):
    self.product_code = [1,2,3,4]
    self.quantity = [70,50,110,10]
    self.material = ['wood', 'metal', 'cork', 'cardboard']
  def __iter__(self):
    yield from map(Product, zip(self.product_code, self.quantity, self.material))
```

Then, in your `flask` app:

```
@app.route('/someroute')
def someroute():
   return flask.render_template('my_template.html', products = productConstuctor())
```

Lastly, `my_template.html` is the same as your original:

```
{% for product in products%}
<div>
  <p>{{product.product_code}}</p>
  <p>{{product.quantity}}</p>
  <p>{{product.material}}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Edit: `map` alternative:

```
class productConstructor:
  ...
  def __iter__(self):
    for i in zip(self.product_code, self.quantity, self.material):
       yield Product(i) #calling Product explicitly
```

Comment: Worked like an absolute dream thank you so much! Brand new to stack overflow and coding in general so don't have the reputation required to upvote but you have my utmost respect! thank you!

Comment: @SimonSikorski Glad to help!

Comment: I've just read about zip and map functions and the one question I do have is with _vals in your init method of the Product class. where does this value get passed from? Is it the zip from your productConstructor iter?

Comment: @SimonSikorski It is actually passed during the execution of the `map` function in `__iter__`. `map(func, vals)` is the same as `[func(i) for i in vals]`. In this case, `func` is called via the implementation of the underlining iteration in `map`. In turn, `Product` is called automatically when mapped over the resulting tuples garnered from `zip(self.product_code, self.quantity, self.material)`.

Comment: Ahh that makes a lot more sense now. So the self in Product __init__ is Product itself and the _val is the return from zip in iter? Still trying to wrap my head around class special methods!

Comment: @SimonSikorski That is right, [`self`](https://medium.com/quick-code/understanding-self-in-python-a3704319e5f0) is the reference and `_val` is the parameter that takes in the result passed to it. I will edit my post with a clearer example of what is transpiring in `__iter__`....